# How to add dashed border around marker using vue2-google-maps

Tags: vue.js, google-maps, nuxt.js, google-maps-markers, vue2-google-maps

[image]

I want to add border around the car image on click of the marker. how can i do it?

```
        <gmap-marker
          :key="index"
          v-for="(m, index) in markers"
          :position="{
            lat: m.location.latitude,
            lng: m.location.longitude,
          }"
          :icon="markerOptions"
        >
        </gmap-marker>
      </gmap-cluster>
```

```
  markerOptions: {
    url: require('~/assets/images/car.svg'),
    scaledSize: { width: 50, height: 50, f: 'px', b: 'px' },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using 2 types of icons - one with your current car icon then another car icon with border.To do this, here are the steps:

1. Put your 2 icons(url) inside the data.

```
 data: {
          center: {
            lat: 10.0,
            lng: 10.0
          },
          icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/donut.png',
          newIcon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/target.png',
```

2. Then you also make a variable for a selected marker flag inside data with value `null`:
    `selectedMarker: null`
3. Inside `<google-marker/>` put a method value in your `@click` then pass the marker and the key:
   `@click="markerClicked(m, key)"`

Then on the methods, declare the `markerClicked` then pass the `key` to the `selectedMarker` you declared earlier. This will hold the value of the key of the selected marker:

```
 markerClicked: function(marker, key) {
            this.selectedMarker = key
          },
```

4. Inside `<google-marker/>` put a method value in your `:icon`. This will handle which icon you will show.
   `:icon=getIcon(key)`

Then on the methods, declare the `getIcon` passing the key. Then you will check if the `selectedMarker` is equal to this key. If yes, this means that this is the active marker and you will show a new Icon which has the border and if it is not equal, you will just show the marker without border.

```
getIcon: function(key) {
            if (this.selectedMarker == key) {
              return this.newIcon
            }else{
            return this.icon
            }
          }
```

Here's a [working code](https://jsfiddle.net/f8cyew9o/).